Stopping audio playblack when another disclosure group is opened in voice recorder app
I'm working on a voice recorder app using SwiftUI. I currently have the player interface in a DisclosureGroup, as so: https://imgur.com/a/GmLvmMh. The audio stops playback when you close the current DisclosureGroup, and also only one DisclosureGroup can be opened at a time. However, I can't make it so that the audio stops playback when opening another DisclosureGroup.
The code for my player is here:
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Player: NSObject, ObservableObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    
    var isPlaying = false {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    
    @Published var currentTime: TimeInterval = 0
    private var timer: AnyCancellable?

    init(soundURL: URL) throws {
        super.init()
        if FileManager().fileExists(atPath: soundURL.path) {
            do {
                self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
                player?.prepareToPlay()
                self.player?.delegate = self
            } catch {
                throw Errors.FailedToPlayURL
            }
        } else {
            print("URL not valid!")
        }
    }
    
    func play() {
        self.player?.play()
        isPlaying = true
        startTimer()
    }
    
    func pause() {
        if isPlaying {
            self.player?.pause()
            isPlaying = false
            stopTimer()
        }
    }
    
    func stop() {
        player?.stop()
        isPlaying = false
        resetPlayback()
    }
    
    func seek(to time: TimeInterval) {
        player?.currentTime = time
        currentTime = time
    }
    
    var duration: TimeInterval {
        player?.duration ?? 0
    }
    
    private func startTimer() {
        timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common)
            .autoconnect()
            .sink { [weak self] _ in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.currentTime = self.player?.currentTime ?? 0
                self.objectWillChange.send()
            }
    }
    
    private func stopTimer() {
        timer?.cancel()
        timer = nil
    }
    
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        if flag {
            isPlaying = false
            stopTimer()
            resetPlayback()
        }
    }
    
    private func resetPlayback() {
        currentTime = 0
        player?.currentTime = 0
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
}


The code for my PlayerViewModel is here:
import Foundation
import Combine

class PlayerViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentTime: TimeInterval = 0
    var player: Player
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private var seekingSubject = PassthroughSubject<TimeInterval, Never>()

    init(player: Player) {
        self.player = player
        self.player.objectWillChange
            .sink { [weak self] in
                self?.currentTime = self?.player.currentTime ?? 0
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        seekingSubject
            .throttle(for: .milliseconds(100), scheduler: RunLoop.main, latest: true)
            .sink { [weak self] time in
                self?.player.seek(to: time)
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func play() {
        player.play()
    }
    
    func pause() {
        player.pause()
    }
    
    func stop() {
        player.stop()
    }
    
    func seek(to time: TimeInterval) {
        seekingSubject.send(time)
    }
    
    var duration: TimeInterval {
        player.duration
    }
}


Finally, the code for my PlayerView is here. Currently, the way I'm detecting a disclosure group is opened is by the URL it's bound to. This way when a disclosure group is opened, opening another one closes the current one. I tried putting viewModel.stop() in here, but to no avail:
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct PlayerView: View {
    @State var soundURL: URL
    @Binding var openedGroup: URL?
    @State private var isOpened: Bool = false

    @StateObject private var viewModel: PlayerViewModel
    @State private var sliderValue: TimeInterval = 0

    init(soundURL: URL, openedGroup: Binding<URL?>) {
        self._soundURL = State(initialValue: soundURL)
        self._openedGroup = openedGroup
        let player = try? Player(soundURL: soundURL)
        self._viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: PlayerViewModel(player: player!))
    }

    var body: some View {
        DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: Binding(
            get: { self.openedGroup == self.soundURL },
            set: { newValue in
                if newValue {
                    self.openedGroup = self.soundURL
                } else if self.openedGroup == self.soundURL {
                    self.openedGroup = nil
                    viewModel.stop()
                }
            }
        )) {
            VStack {
                Slider(value: $sliderValue, in: 0...viewModel.duration, onEditingChanged: { editing in
                    if editing {
                        viewModel.pause()
                    } else {
                        viewModel.seek(to: sliderValue)
                        viewModel.play()
                    }
                })
                .padding()
                .onChange(of: viewModel.currentTime) {
                    sliderValue = viewModel.currentTime
                }

                HStack {
                    Text(timeString(from: viewModel.currentTime))
                    Spacer()
                    Text(timeString(from: viewModel.duration))
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)

                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: viewModel.player.isPlaying ? "pause.fill" : "play.fill")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            if viewModel.player.isPlaying {
                                viewModel.pause()
                            } else {
                                viewModel.play()
                            }
                        }
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
                FileNameButtonView(soundURL: soundURL)
            }
        } label: {
            Text(soundURL.lastPathComponent)
        }
    }

    private func timeString(from timeInterval: TimeInterval) -> String {
        let minutes = Int(timeInterval) / 60
        let seconds = Int(timeInterval) % 60
        return String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
    }
}

If you want to take a look at the full repo, it is here: https://github.com/aabagdi/MemoMan/.
Thanks for any help!
